# LWUIT4IO (v1.5) ConnectionRequest's readResponse() Issue - Nokia SDK 2.0

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I have been porting an existing J2ME mobile app, that allows users to view archived news videos, to the latest **Nokia SDK 2.0** platform for Series 40 full-touch devices.

I am using both the **LWUIT** and **LWUIT4IO** technologies for the UI and Network functionalities of the application respectively.

The app has been tested to work on the **S40 5th Edition SDK** platform emulator. Extending LWUIT4IO's **ConnectionRequest** class and utilizing LWUIT's **XMLParser**, the app can successfully send a HTTP request and get the expected response data from a web service that basically returns an XML-formatted type of feed (containing necessary metadata for the video) (Here's the URL of the web service: http://nokiamusic.myxph.com/nokianewsfeed.aspx?format=3gp)

But for some reason, this is not the case when trying to run the app on the latest Nokia SDK 2.0 platform. It throws a *java.lang.NullPointerException* upon trying to parse (XMLParser.parse()) the **InputStream** response of the web service. When I trace the *Network Traffic Monitor* of the emulator of the corresponding Request sent and Response received - 0 bytes were returned as content despite a successful response status 200. Apparently the XMLParser object has nothing to parse in the first place.

I am hoping that you can somehow shed light on this issue or share any related resolutions, or help me further refine the problem.

Posted below is the code of the *SegmentService* class (a sub-class of LWUIT's ConnectionRequest) that connects to the webservice and processes the XML response:

```
public class SegmentService extends ConnectionRequest implements ParserCallback {

    private Vector segments;
    private Video segment;

    public SegmentService(String backend) {
        String slash = backend.endsWith("/") ? "" : "/";
        setPost(false);
        setUrl(backend + slash + "nokianewsfeed.aspx");
        addArgument("format", "3gp");
    }

    public void setDateFilter(String date) {
        System.out.println(date);
        addArgument("date", date);
    }

    private Video getCurrent() {
        if (segment == null) {
            segment = new Video();
        }
        return segment;
    }

    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader i = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"); 
        XMLParser xmlparser = new XMLParser();

        System.out.println("Parsing the xml...");
        Element element = xmlparser.parse(i);
        System.out.println("Root " + element.getTagName());

        int max = element.getNumChildren();
        System.out.println("Number of children: " + max);

        segments = new Vector();

        for (int c = 0; c < max; c++) {
            Element e = element.getChildAt(c);
            System.out.println("segment " + c);

            int len = e.getNumChildren();
            System.out.println("Number of children: " + len);

            for (int d=0; d<len; d++) {
                Element s = e.getChildAt(d);
                String property = s.getTagName();
                System.out.println("key: " + property);
                String value = (s.getNumChildren()>0) ? s.getChildAt(0).getText() : null;
                System.out.println("value: " + value);

                if (property.equals("title")) {
                    getCurrent().setTitle(value);
                } else if (property.equals("description")) {
                    getCurrent().setDescription(value);
                } else if (property.equals("videourl")) {
                    getCurrent().setVideoUrl(value);
                } else if (property.equals("thumburl")) {
                    getCurrent().setThumbUrl(value);
                } else if (property.equals("adurl")) {
                    getCurrent().setAdUrl(value);
                } else if (property.equals("publishdate")) {
                    getCurrent().setPublishDate(value);
                } else if (property.equals("category")) {
                    getCurrent().setCategory(value);
                } else if (property.equals("weburl")) {
                    getCurrent().setWebUrl(value);
                } else if (property.equals("thumburl2")) {
                    getCurrent().setThumb210(value);
                } else if (property.equals("thumburl4")) {
                    getCurrent().setThumb40(value);
                }
            }

            if (segment != null) {
                segments.addElement(segment);
                segment = null;
            }
        }
        fireResponseListener(new NetworkEvent(this, segments));
    }

    public boolean parsingError(int errorId, String tag, String attribute, String value, String description) {
        System.out.println(errorId);
        System.out.println(tag);
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(description);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably because the URL is not returning anything for it to parse, check the Http response code sent from the server.